# How to label arrows in this commuting cube?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels

I would like to draw a commuting cube, where all the edges are also labeled. Below is my cube but I don't know how to do this, as the `stackrel` doesnt seem to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin= 1.1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}

\title{Essays}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
back line/.style={densely dotted},
cross line/.style={preaction={draw=white, -,
line width=6pt}}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
row sep=3em, column sep=3em,
text height=1.5ex,
text depth=0.25ex]{
& S\left(a,b\right) & & S'\left(a,b\right) \\
S\left(a',b\right) & & S'\left(a',b\right)  \\
& S\left(a,b'\right) & & S'\left(a,b'\right) \\
S\left(a',b'\right)  & & S'\left(a',b'\right) \\
};
\path[->]
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-4)
edge (m-2-1)
edge [back line] (m-3-2)
(m-1-4) edge (m-3-4)
edge (m-2-3)
(m-2-1) edge [cross line] (m-2-3)
edge (m-4-1)
(m-3-2) edge [back line] (m-3-4)
edge [back line] (m-4-1)
(m-4-1) edge (m-4-3)
(m-3-4) edge (m-4-3)
(m-2-3) edge [cross line] (m-4-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `(a) edge node {l} (b)` creates an edge between `a` and `b` while creating a node with contents `l` over the edge (midway). Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks Bordaigorl. Edge node {l} works, but I can not write in math mode withing brackets, for instance:  (a) edge node {\psi \left(a,b\right)} (b)

Comment: @user36679 Enclose the math between dollars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tikz-cd` package is, in general, useful for drawing commutative diagrams more easily than with `tikz` directly.  Here's some code based on your diagram intended to illustrate a number of options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[back line/.style={densely dotted}, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
& S(a,b) \ar{dl}[swap]{\psi(a',b)} \ar{rr}{\bar{\psi}(a,b)} \ar[back line]{dd}[near end]{\psi(a,b')} 
  & & S'(a,b) \ar{dd}{\psi'(a,b')} \ar{dl}[swap,sloped,near start]{\psi'(a',b)} \\
S(a',b) \ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{\bar{\psi}(a',b)} \ar{dd}[swap]{\psi(a',b')} 
  & & S'(a',b) \\
& S(a,b') \ar[back line]{rr} \ar[back line]{dl} 
  & & S'(a,b') \ar{dl} \\
S(a',b') \ar{rr} & & S'(a',b') \ar[crossing over, leftarrow]{uu}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Dear Charles, I tried to modify the above diagram, particularly by labelling all the horizontal arrows going from left to right, by  $\psi(a,b)$. I spent about an hour on this but yet unsucessful. Would you please kindly help me to complete this as I am about to miss my deadline, for being so ignorant of latex. I would gladdy acknowledge you in my essay anyway.

Comment: Here is my incomplete attempt:\begin{tikzcd}[back line/.style={densely dotted}, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
& S(a,b) \ar{dl}[swap]{S(g,b)} \ar{rr}{\psi(a,b)} \ar[back line]{dd}[near end]{S(a,f)} 
  & & S'(a,b) \ar{dd}{S'(a,f)} \ar{dl}[swap,sloped,near start]{S'(g,b)} \\
S(a',b) \ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{\psi(a',b)} \ar{dd}[swap]{S(a',f)} 
  & & S'(a',b) \\
& S(a,b') \ar[back line]{rr} \ar[back line]{dl}{S(a',g)} 
  & & S'(a,b') \ar{dl} \\
S(a',b') \ar{rr} & & S'(a',b') \ar[crossing over, leftarrow]{uu} 
\end{tikzcd}

Comment: @user36679: So far, your attempt looks good. The general format for a right arrow in this diagram is `\ar[arrow options]{rr}[label options]{label}`. Note that the label is automatically in math mode; there is no need to add dollar signs.

Comment: @user36679: If you can show me what you have tried that did not work, perhaps I can get a better sense of your difficulties.

Comment: @ Charles Staats: Thank you very much for the generosity. It worked. Berakot.